# How to add child object in parent object in EF

Tags: .net, entity-framework, generics, parent-child

Work on EF4.

I know EF ObjectContext  can be three properties involved in a parent-child association, two navigation properties (`parent.Children`, `child.Parent`) and a foreign key property (`child.ParentId`). I need help on `parent.Childer` navigation.

```
private List<T2> FillChildControlOnSave<T1, T2>(BOMMasterController objController, List<T2> entityDetail, T1 objEntity)
            where T1 : PlnBOMMaster
            where T2 : PlnBOMDetail
{
    #region MyRegion        

    #endregion

    foreach (T2 c in entityDetail)
    {
        if (c.Action == XERP.Entity.ActionMode.Add)
        {
            objEntity.PlnBOMDetails.Add(c);
        }

        if (c.Action == XERP.Entity.ActionMode. Update)
        {
            objEntity.PlnBOMDetails.Add(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Want to replace `objEntity.PlnBOMDetails.Add(c);` with generic `objEntity.###<T2>.Add(c);`. Help me to writa a generic syntax for the above  add and update condition .
If have any question please ask, Any type of suggestion will be acceptable.Thanks in advanced.